Firebase Multi-Factor Authentication Suddenly Failing with 500 Internal Server Error for Hungary phone numbers
Once authenticated with e-mail and password, the identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v2/accounts/mfaSignIn:start call fails:
{
"error": {
"code": 500,
"message": "Internal error encountered.",
"status": "INTERNAL"
}
}

This error occurred with +36 phone prefixes followed by 9 digits (Hungary). I've double-checked with distinct users with the same country prefix: same issue.
I've tried to update the users, replacing the phone numbers with +41 (Switzerland) and +34 (Spain) and it worked properly. I'm wondering if it's a regional issue or something.

Update:
I also opened a support ticket at Google for this issue, and got this answer:
Services are available in nearby regions, so it is not a problem with Google data centers.
Firebase services are healthy and stable.
The problem seems to be localized in this region and for some Carriers.
To ensure the safety and reliability of our services, carriers or entire regions with consistently low SMS success rates may become temporarily unavailable. Given this information, there is not much that we can do to improve the availability.
We apologize that we do not have better news or options for you at this time. To continue using Firebase Authentication in this region, I recommend considering using a different authentication method such as email and password or TOTP multi-factor. Alternatively, we also offer the ability to integrate a custom auth system.
